# ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files') + mongoose, React, express, mongoDB, node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting a error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')"
I want to be able to upload a video into my media bucket, but when clicking its link to stream the uploaded video I get the following error

```
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server is running on : http://localhost:8000
MongoDB is connected!
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')
unable to fetch files
```

I notice that the "files" in `const files =await gfs.files.find().toArray()` is not highlighted and I think there is a issue with this line. I am just not sure what exactly.

Sometimes the video links will show up and I am able to delete them, but when I click on them all I receive is a "{}" in the route

server.js:

```
app.get('/files',async(req,res)=>{
try{
  const files =await gfs.files.find().toArray()

  res.json(files)

}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
  console.log("unable to fetch file")
  res.status(400).send(err)
}
```

app.js

```
  const fetchFiles = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/files");
    setFiles(res.data);
  }, []);
```

gfs is defined here

```
let gfs;
//mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const conn = mongoose.connection
// create a stream connection with our cluster
conn.once('open', async() => {
  //Init Stream
  gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
    bucketName: 'media'
  })
  gfs = await Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('media');
})
```

Comment: `gfs.files` is undefined. What is `gfs` and where is it defined?

Comment: I have added the code above and it is defined in my server.js.  gfs = await Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);

Comment: It seems like you need to put the `app.get` inside of the `conn.once` callback

Comment: i am not exactly sure what you mean by that I have other routes that use gfs like my delete route. wouldn't that cause more issues? Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)